# Should we nuke the [number] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The number tag wiki is this:

> This challenge is intended to be solved by using, manipulating, accepting as input, or outputting numeric values.

This is pretty vague. What I'm understanding from this is the number tag should be applied any time the digits 0-9 even tenuously relate to the challenge.

Examples:

- [Is this a number?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103441/is-this-a-number]) was tagged [number] for obvious reasons.  This challenge relates to evaluating strings into numbers (mostly).
- [Find all the coordinates on a path](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105649/find-all-the-coordinates-on-a-path) was tagged [number] because the output is coordinate pairs of 2 numbers.
- [Generate an ascii-art non-intersecting path](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105808/generate-an-ascii-art-non-intersecting-path) was tagged [number] because it takes input in the form of 2 numbers.
- [Coprimes up to N](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104665/coprimes-up-to-n) was tagged [number] because it requires finding a set of positive numbers that fit criteria.

All of these challenges have the tag for a different reason.  Input as numbers, output as numbers, math involving numbers, and evaluating number literals.

Can we burninate the tag and possibly replace it with more specific ones, such as [numerical-io](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-io) or [literal-evaluation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literal-evaluation) (for challenges relating to evaluating literals of any sort)?

Downside to burnination is that there are *many, many* (536) questions tagged [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number), and it might be unfeasible to replace the tag everywhere.

Comment: I really don't think there are enough challenges to specify this tag. Nobody would type such a tag in the search bar.

Comment: @devRicher eh, I can think of reasons why you would want to search for number challenges.

Comment: What im saying is that I would search for number or integer, but not numerical-io.

Comment: @devRicher ah, I see.  Even if you didn't use it to search for them, possibly for dupe-marking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think burnination is all that necessary, but I would definitely be in favor of dropping a couple of the criteria. I don't think "it takes numbers as input" in particular makes sense (the two path questions given, for example).

Maybe worded something like this, but someone else could probably do better:

> This challenge is intended to be solved by using or manipulating numeric values.

Comment: Retagging would make the most sense to me, either as we come across them or as a concentrated effort.